# Authorize Register Page in ASP.NET Core 2.1 with Identity UI as a library

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a Razor Pages project in .NET Core 2.1.3 with ASP.NET Core Identity.

I was wondering, if it is possible to Authorize the 'Register'-page, with Identity [as a prebuilt UI](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/02/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/), without scaffolding all the identity related code back. Only registered users (optimally role-based) should be able to register new users.

I have tried adding the following in the `Startup.cs`-file, but neither is doing the trick:

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Admin");
    // Trying to authorize the Register-page
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Register");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Pages/Account/Register");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Identity/Account/Register");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Register");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Identity/Pages/Account/Register");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Identity/Pages/Account");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Identity/Account");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Areas/Identity/Pages");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Areas/Identity");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Areas");
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Alternatively, is it possible to disable registering new users altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up scaffolding the Identity-pages as described in the link and authorized the Register page with `[Authorize]`. If anyone comes up with a solution, however, I'm still curious!

Comment: I also want to know how to do this, without scaffolding the identity pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me, and uses role based authorisation. I still had to scaffold some pages, but only the ones that needed updating.

**Scaffold Login and Register pages**

I only scaffolded the Login and Register pages using the following:

[Scaffold identity into a Razor project with authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-a-razor-project-with-authorization)

This is also helpful. There is a demo showing the above:

[What's new in Web Development with ASP.NET Core 2.1 : Build 2018](https://youtu.be/SEgyZRau0rU?t=1787)

Login.cshtml - I commented out the following.

```
<p>
    <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
</p>
```

Register.cshtml.cs - I removed the AllowAnonymous attribute

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
```

**Startup.cs - ConfigureServices**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>{
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    })
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    // Register no-op EmailSender used by account confirmation and password reset during development
    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
    services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
            policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
        options.DefaultPolicy = options.GetPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole");
    });

    services.AddMvc()
       .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/About", "RequireAdministratorRole");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Register");
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much. I actually found out about the scaffolding of individual pages as described in the first link just a couple of hours ago, and was going to post it as an answer. But I appreciate it and the demo code!